# What is the best way to make a loop HTTPrequest calling?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to know what is the best way to make a loop that calls Httprequest using javascript ?

Comment: Are you wanting to pull data from a database?

Comment: no i just want to get the responseText and put it in an innerHTML of a div

Comment: And where is the responsive text coming from? I'm on about he actual text, not the JavaScript.

Comment: a page from facebook

Comment: Lol and do you have the Facebook SDK set up and ready to pull data from Facebook?

Comment: If not I recommend you look into getting that done first

Comment: i just need to capture some divs from the html of that page not the data

Comment: could you help me make a loop containing an http requests called per iteration

Comment: The divs display data from Facebooks database.

Comment: Afraid it's not quite as simple as you'd hoped.

Comment: look what i mean is i will take the resposetext and place it in an innerhtml of a div i have and then target the divs i want from the there